liquibase throws illegal argument exception on key 'create'
Using liquibase:4.27.0 with the following changelog/changeset throws the following error...
liquibase.properties
changeLogFile: changelog/changeset.yml
url: jdbc:postgresql://my-postgres-server:5432/my-db
driver: org.postgresql.Driver
classpath: /liquibase/internal/lib/postgresql.jar
defaultSchemaName: my_schema

changelog/changeset.yml
databaseChangeLog:
  - changeSet:
      id: initial-views
      author: Banana Man
      runOnChange: true
      changes:
        - createView:
          schema_name: my_schema
          path: path/to/my/view.sql
          viewName: my_view
          fullDefinition: true
          replaceIfExists: true

view.sql
select *
from banana
limit 100;

I guess lastly I should add that I'm running this from a liquibase container
docker run -it -v /file-location:/on-container liquibase bash

The error I get form a liquibase update-sql is as follows
$liquibase update-sql

...
SET SEARCH_PATH TO my_schema, "$user","public";

ERROR: Exception Details
ERROR: Exception Primary Class: IllegalArgumentException
ERROR: Exception Primary Reason: Key 'create' is not defined
ERROR: Exception Primary Source: PostgreSQL 15.7

Unexpected error running Liquibase: Migration failed for changeset mychangelog.yml::initial-views::Banana Man:
    Reason: java.lang.IllegalArguementException: Key 'create' is not defined
...

What am I doing wrong?

You do not need to include fullDefinition: true in the changeset's changes.
